# How wallet handles different cryptocurrencies?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, address, bip32-hd-wallets, ethereum

As far as I know, wallet stores private and public keys and calculate balance according to that.
Suppose a wallet(Single cryptocurrency) has 3 keys (private,public). Wallet will find UTXO's connected to those keys and display balance on your wallet UI.

But if a wallet handles different cryptocurrencies, how does it distinguishes between different cryptocurrencies? How does it know available public address belongs to a particular currency (Blockchain)?

Answer (score 1):

Typically there's a seed which is displayed as a sequence of 12-24 words that is used to derive addresses/private keys in different chains. Different coins use different *derivation paths* which are hardcoded in the wallet so even if two coins use the same address format the generated addresses will be different.